# Moving two elements from series to parallel

Tags: voltage, power, resistors

I got a small pizza oven with two elements (top and bottom), they are rated 115V 600W and they are connected in series, as we have 230V in Europe.

Everything works fine, but I would like to control those two elements independently (so I will need to connect them in parallel), unfortunately that is not going to work with 230V, what is the best solution, in your opinion, to connect them in parallel and still have them operate within their rated conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just connect them in parallel.

If you're fluent with this stuff, you can drive each one directly from 230 V, but with PWM so that the average power doesn't exceed 600 W.  There are various ways to do this, including triacs, but there are issues beyond what we can reasonably get into here.  You have to consider what happens when the system screws up and applies the full 230 V.  In that case the power dissipation will be 4 times intended, or 2.4 kW, for a short while.  That will damage the element quickly, and possibly other things around it.

Another option is to use a transformer to make 115 V, then drive each element independently from that.  That will work fine with less chance of catastrophic failure, but will require a big, klunky, and expensive 50 Hz power transformer.

Answer (score 1):

The crude but secure and working solution:
Get a 230V primary / 110V secondary isolating transformer used for US equipment in europe with about 2kVA and use that for your oven. Since you're working on 110V, now, you can easily connect them in parallel. They are not that cheap though.

Any other solution involves complicated electronics which might fail after 5-10 years, damaging your heating elements in the process. A transformer will just work for centuries. :D

*EDIT: Why 2kVA? Because you have to account for losses in the transformer and it's better to have a safety margin in there.

Answer (score 0):

An even cruder solution would be to find a second oven, and use those elements as ballast resistors.  You could leave them inside their oven and just let them get hot.  Not the best solution, but lighter and cheaper than a step-down transformer.

Comment: I think a 600W halogen light bulb would also work, and you can get ready made flood lights that make for a nice enclosure.

Comment: Yes, but you do have the challenge of matching resistance if you use "something else".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rectifier diode in series with each heating element - it should half the average power, so if your heating element draws 1200W @ 230 V, then with diode in series it would draw only 600W. However I'm not sure about safety of this solution.

Comment: This doesn't work.  Power is proportional to the square of the voltage.  Without a diode, each heating element would dissipate 2.4 kW at 230 V.  A diode would halve that to only 1.2 kW, still twice what the heating element is rated for.